# How to get rid of duplicates from random name generator?

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make a random generator that selects a specific number of names from a list and pairs them together.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Brown\source\repos\Generator\bin\names.txt");

            List<string> source = new List<string>();
            int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                source.Add(lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)]);
            }
            string joinNames = string.Join(" x ", source);

            genResult.Text = joinNames;
        }
```

I got it to work but when i click the generate button I see duplicates of some names.

Comment: Does the file contains duplicate name?

Comment: You're using `new Random()` incorrectly. Only create a *single* instance of `Random`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than loading your data into an array, you should use a collection like a List.  Then as you randomly select items from the list, you should remove the record you just selected.

```
List<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Brown\source\repos\Generator\bin\names.txt").ToList();
int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
Random rnd = new Random();
List<string> source = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var tmp = lines[rnd.Next(lines.Count)];
    source.Add(tmp);
    lines.Remove(tmp);
}
string joinNames = string.Join(" x ", source);

genResult.Text = joinNames;
```

Comment: Ya it good but creating new  `new Random()` for every iteration is not a good idea. i think we can use same object.

Comment: Agree, best to declare that outside of the main loop.

Comment: Since comments here agree with something I agree that this is the second worst solution (the top one is to check if number already picked).

Answer (score 1):

To select `n` distinct names instead of the `for` loop just do this:

```
Random rnd=new Random();
source=lines.OrderBy(x=>rnd.Next()).Take(n);
```

Explanation: it will order the line elements in a random order then assigns the first `n` elements to `source`

The above solution is not optimal cause it uses the `OrderBy` method which currently(a Quicksort variant) executes in O(n*log(n)). You can use optimal solution using `Fisher-Yates shuffle` as introduced in [Randomize a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: Please review proper way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt so you can provide better clones of that in the future (ideally you'd just vote as duplicate instead of suggesting suboptimal approach without corresponding waranings)